# Second order PDE with initial and boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following PDE:

$u=u(x,y)$

$\left\{
  \begin{array}{1 1}
    \partial_x ^2 u-6\cdot\partial_x \partial_yu+9\cdot\partial_x^2u=x^2+y^2\ \\
   \ u(0,y)=0  \\
\partial_x u(0,y)=y \ 
  \end{array} \right.$

From the canonical form I found:

$u(x,y)=\frac{10}{12}x^4+\frac{(3x+y)^2}{2}x^2-x^3(3x+y)+c(3x+y)x+d(3x+y)$

where $c,d \in C^2(\mathbb{R})$

I don't know hot to proceed from here, if I plug in the initial condition values, I don't get the solution.

Thanks in advance!